# Create Configurable Extension in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, extensions

I am creating a configurable extension for ArcGIS desktop 10.1

I am not using Add-on , so please don't suggest add-on.

How can I disable some toolbars and commands, when the extension is disabled?
I want to disable users from adding toolbars from the "Customize" interface in ArcMap, when the extension is disabled?

Is there a way even to hide the toolbar from the "Customize" interface of GIS desktop when the extension is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

Rebecca Zeckoski goes into detail in her blog post titled [Capturing Button Clicks in ArcObjects](http://rzeckoskiengineering.blogspot.com/2012/06/capturing-button-clicks-in-arcobjects.html).  The following is an (untested) adaptation of her code.

```vb
Public Class clsCustomizationFilter
  Implements ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICustomizationFilter


  Public Function OnCustomizationEvent(custEventType As _
   ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.esriCustomizationEvent, eventCtx As Object) As Boolean _
   Implements ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICustomizationFilter.OnCustomizationEvent

   If custEventType = ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.esriCustomizationEvent.esriCEShowCustDlg Then
        Return False
   End If


   Return True

End Function
```

Apply the filter to the app:

```
m_Filter = New clsCustomizationFilter
My.ArcMap.Application.LockCustomization("password", m_Filter)
```